# I gave someone a key to my place while I'm gone. If they steal from me, am I covered under renter's insurance?

Tags: united-states, insurance, negligence

Would I need to prove/argue that it was reasonable to trust that person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is whether your insurance covers against loss from theft. If [these people](https://www.progressive.com/answers/does-renters-insurance-cover-theft/) are typical, you are probably covered. Policies are not generally limited to burglary losses, they cover all theft loses, including for example when a child steals from their parents. You will have to cooperate in their attempts to recover from the thief, so you can't refuse to identify the person.